# Stretchy, segmented footer misbehaving. Compact live example given

Tags: css, css-float, footer, css-position, image-segmentation

I need to have a curve-shaped stretchy footer fixed at the bottom of the browser window, where the curve is an image.  I've mocked up a [live example](http://test.nesevis.info/footer/).

To minimize the loss of "clickable" real-estate in lower layers through the transparent part of the footer image, my instinct is to cut the image into several segments (red boxes in the example) and position them next to each other like so:

```css
#arc-segment-1,
#arc-segment-2 {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0px;
}
#arc-segment-1 {
   width: 5%; /* where this */
   height: 82px;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(...);
}
#arc-segment-2 {
   width: 5%;
   height: 72px;
   left: 5%; /* matches this */
   background-image: url(...);
}
```

In most major browsers (not IE and FF), **hairline fractures come and go between boxes as the window is resized**, which is unacceptable.

Floating the image segments would solve the problem, but I have not found a way of implementing it that still fixes the footer to the bottom and preserve the mentioned "clickability". Is there a better approach to this problem than mine, or can it somehow be remedied?

*Note regarding the example given: The curve image itself in the example has not yet been cut, it is still a single image. Also, the blue boxes are not a concern, they will not stretch so they are not affected by the problem.*

I'd be interested in both the reasons of this behavior and any workable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events)`: none;` so you can click below

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it is an interesting experimental property that may become very useful. The current lack of support in many browsers makes it unsuitable for me as of now though...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over a somewhat workable solution myself while reading at the W3C:

If the width-property of the segments is taken out and both left and right properties are given, say for a 10% wide segment in the middle of the screen:

```css
#arc-segment-3 {
   left: 45%;
   right: 45%;
}
```

It will behave like originally intended, although some browsers now seem to overlap the segments with a hairline instead. In my case, this is a much smaller problem as the texture of the arc is weak enough not to be much noticeable. Anyone with a pixel-perfect approach?